# Main tab needs subtabs nested using html,css and javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

When user clicks on a tab, another tab should popup within the main tab and according to the second tab selection input fields should popup and others hide. something like expedia.com  nested tabs basically with input fields

I have tried the tab view option and input fields,but i am unable to get the second tab view under the main tabs.

I need the same way [expedia](https://www.expedia.co.uk/) does

and submit button should work for individual tabs.

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tabs li:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

.tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: rgba(219,219,219,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4B5056;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.tabs a + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs :target a { background: rgba(219,219,219,0); }

.tabs :target a + div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.tabs a { width: 100%; }

.tabs a + div {
  position: static;
  float: left;
}

.tabs li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}
}

input {
    display:block;
}

textarea {
    display:block;
}

select {
    display:block;
}

p {
    color:#000000;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
h3 {
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h3>Travel Registration Form</h3>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li id="option1">
      <a href="#option1">Complex</a>
      <div>
         <p  class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel"   ><span   class="form__input"  >Traveler's Information </span> </p> 
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="name"> <span class="form__label"> Traveler Name </span><input class="form__input"   id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" />
</label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="email">Email<input class="form__input" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" > No Of Travellers:<input  id="00N8E000002AUuY" name="00N8E000002AUuY" size="20" type="text" class="form__input" /></label><br>



<p class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" ><span class="form__input">Trip Info</span></p>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" >
Travel Options:<select  id="00N8E000002AjRq"   class="form__input"   name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options">
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
<option value="Flight + Hotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
<option value="Flight + Hotel + Transfer">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Flight + Transfer">Flight + Transfer</option>
<option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Hotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Transfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Train + Hotel">Train + Hotel</option>
<option value="Train + Hotel + Transfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
<option value="Hotel + Transfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br></label><br>




<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" >Special Requirements:<textarea  id="00N8E000002AXcw" name="00N8E000002AXcw" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>

<br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="option2">
      <a href="#option2">Enquiry</a>
      <div>
          <h2>Heading 2</h2>
          <p>Fill your details</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="option3">
      <a href="#option3">Transfer</a>
      <div>
          <h2>Transfer</h2>
         
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Address:<textarea class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcS" name="00N8E000002AXcS" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Date:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><input class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcX" name="00N8E000002AXcX" size="12" type="date" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Time:<span class="timeContainer"><input class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcc" name="00N8E000002AXcc" placeholder="HH:MM" size="12" type="time" /></span></label><br>
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Date:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><input class="form__input"  id="00N8E000002AXcm" name="00N8E000002AXcm" size="12" type="date" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Time:<span class="timeContainer"><input class="form__input"  id="00N8E000002AXcr" name="00N8E000002AXcr" placeholder="HH:MM" size="12" type="time" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Address:<textarea class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXch" name="00N8E000002AXch" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @harish kumar

Answer (score 0):

You used "href" attribute so the page default action of top is showing. Need to add some script to stop the default action.
Try the below code:

```js
$('.tabs li a').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('.tab_content').css({
    "height": "0px",
    "overflow": "hidden"
  });
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $('.tab_content[data-id="'+ id +'"]').css({
    "height": "100%",
    "overflow": "visible"
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tabs li:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

.tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: rgba(219,219,219,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4B5056;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.tabs a + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs :target a { background: rgba(219,219,219,0); }

.tabs :target a + div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.tabs a { width: 100%; }

.tabs a + div {
  position: static;
  float: left;
}

.tabs li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
}
}

input {
    display:block;
}

textarea {
    display:block;
}

select {
    display:block;
}

p {
    color:#000000;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
h3 {
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:50px;
}
<form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <h3>Travel Registration Form</h3>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li id="option1">
      <a href="#option1">Complex</a>
      <div class="tab_content" data-id="#option1">
         <p  class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel"   ><span   class="form__input"  >Traveler's Information </span> </p> 
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="name"> <span class="form__label"> Traveler Name </span><input class="form__input"   id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" />
</label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="email">Email<input class="form__input" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" > No Of Travellers:<input  id="00N8E000002AUuY" name="00N8E000002AUuY" size="20" type="text" class="form__input" /></label><br>



<p class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" ><span class="form__input">Trip Info</span></p>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" >
Travel Options:<select  id="00N8E000002AjRq"   class="form__input"   name="00N8E000002AjRq" title="Travel Options">
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Flight">Flight</option>
<option value="Flight + Hotel">Flight + Hotel</option>
<option value="Flight + Hotel + Transfer">Flight + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Flight + Transfer">Flight + Transfer</option>
<option value="Eurostar">Eurostar</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Hotel">Eurostar + Hotel</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer">Eurostar + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Eurostar + Transfer">Eurostar + Transfer</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Train + Hotel">Train + Hotel</option>
<option value="Train + Hotel + Transfer">Train + Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
<option value="Hotel + Transfer">Hotel + Transfer</option>
<option value="Transfer">Transfer</option>
</select><br></label><br>




<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" >Special Requirements:<textarea  id="00N8E000002AXcw" name="00N8E000002AXcw" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>

<br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="option2"> 
      <a href="#option2">Enquiry</a>
      <div class="tab_content" data-id="#option2">
          <h2>Heading 2</h2>
          <p>Fill your details</p>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li id="option3">
      <a href="#option3">Transfer</a>
      <div class="tab_content" data-id="#option3">
          <h2>Transfer</h2> 
         
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Address:<textarea class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcS" name="00N8E000002AXcS" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Date:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><input class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcX" name="00N8E000002AXcX" size="12" type="date" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Pick Up Time:<span class="timeContainer"><input class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXcc" name="00N8E000002AXcc" placeholder="HH:MM" size="12" type="time" /></span></label><br>
<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Date:<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"><input class="form__input"  id="00N8E000002AXcm" name="00N8E000002AXcm" size="12" type="date" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Time:<span class="timeContainer"><input class="form__input"  id="00N8E000002AXcr" name="00N8E000002AXcr" placeholder="HH:MM" size="12" type="time" /></span></label><br>

<label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel" >Drop Address:<textarea class="form__input"   id="00N8E000002AXch" name="00N8E000002AXch" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></label><br>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Added data-attr to content div and added class too. Review the code.

Comment: is there a way i can do this with pure javascript only without library